# JavaScript: Half-working formula for orbit camera

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, 3d

I've been working with [phoria.js](http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/) and have really got a kick out of it. I have a player avatar model and have been using a first person camera. The phoria.js camera is positioned with two coordinates of 3D space: the first: the camera's actual position in the scene graph, the second: the point which the camera looks at. I've been using two angles: `angleX` and `angleY` defined in degrees (I know that radians are better) for easy thinking as well as a constant distance of 10 units.

The code for the fp camera goes like

```
{within an object definition}
setLookAtByAngle: function(camera, angleX, angleY) {
    lookAt = {x: camera.position.x, y: camera.position.y, z: camera.position.z};
    extent = 10;

    lookAt.x += Math.tan(angleX * (Math.PI / 180)) * extent;
    lookAt.y += Math.tan(angleY * (Math.PI / 180)) * extent;
    lookAt.z += extent;

    camera.lookat = lookAt;
},

getAngleByLookAt: function(camera) {
    xPlanarLookAt = {x: camera.lookat.x, y: camera.position.y, z: camera.lookat.z};
    yPlanarLookAt = {x: camera.position.x, y: camera.lookat.y, z: camera.lookat.z};

    hypotX = getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(camera.position, xPlanarLookAt);
    oppX = Math.abs(camera.lookat.x - camera.position.x);
    angleX = Math.asin(oppX / hypotX) * (180/Math.PI);

    hypotY = getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(camera.position, yPlanarLookAt);
    oppY = Math.abs(camera.lookat.y - camera.position.y);
    angleY = Math.asin(oppY / hypotY) * (180/Math.PI);

    return {x: angleX, y: angleY};
},
{continue object definition}
```

. What I have so far of the third person camera uses my own `SpaceUtils`. It takes the observee's position[1](http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/) and the inverted x[2],y[3] angles and calls `SpaceUtils.translateByAngle([1], [2], [3], 10)` with 10 as a distance constant to be modified later along with FOV when I add zooming functionality.

`SpaceUtils` looks like

```
SpaceUtils = {
    degSin: function(theta) {
        return Math.sin(theta * (Math.PI / 180));
    },
    degCos: function(theta) {
        return Math.cos(theta * (Math.PI / 180));
    },
    degTan: function(theta) {
        return Math.tan(theta * (Math.PI / 180));
    },

    translateByAngle: function(pos, angleX, angleY, distance) {
        dest = {x: pos.x, y: pos.y, z: pos.z};

        dest.z += distance * SpaceUtils.degSin(angleY);
        hyp     = distance * SpaceUtils.degCos(angleY);
        dest.x += hyp      * SpaceUtils.degCos(angleX);
        dest.y += hyp      * SpaceUtils.degSin(angleX);

        return dest;
    }
};
```

My calculator has Pol() and Rec() functions which do the job in 2D.
I supposed I just need the correct one of these for 3D, so I began implementing. It all works in the four `x > 0` quadrants, but pushes the camera down as I transition across `x == 0` where `y > 0` (y is up-down axis) so that when I start with `x > 0` and `y > 0`, I end up with `x < 0` and `y < 0` when `y > 0` should be the case.

In short, I need a 3D Rec(r, theta) function ideally in degrees, but radians is fine if it's not purpose written.

I realise that this is a sizable ask, so I'll bounty 50 or 100 rep if it comes to that.

Comment: Here I would suggest that your life could be so much easier, and that you could find so many more examples applicable to your needs, if you used a matrix/quat library instead of this kind of scalar logic involving rectangular<->polar coordinates. That said, if you're still interested anyway, check out spherical coordinates.

Comment: This question needs to be simmered down a bit into the thing you're actually asking for. You want a function that takes angles and gives you what? How are the angles defined? Can you give us a set of values that you are expecting to get out of the function with the matching inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phoria uses x as forward-backward, y as upward-downward, and z as sideways, while conventional mathematics swaps the purposes of y and z. You should to. That last function in `SpaceUtils` should go something more along the lines of the follwing.

```
translateByAngle: function(pos, angleX, angleY, distance) {
    dest = {x: pos.x, y: pos.y, z: pos.z};

    dest.y += distance * SpaceUtils.degSin(angleY);
    hyp     = distance * SpaceUtils.degCos(angleY);
    dest.x += hyp      * SpaceUtils.degSin(angleX);
    dest.z += hyp      * SpaceUtils.degCos(angleX);

    return dest;
}
```